# How to use TransactionScope class to use same connection without starting a transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure `A` that creates a [global temporary table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) (prefixed with `##`) where it inserts some temporary data. Then, I have a stored procedure `B` that consumes this data. Hence, `A` and `B` must be called during the same session (connection). Otherwise the temporary table will be dropped.

My database framework constantly use a construct as follows:

```
public T GetSomeData()
{
    using (var connection = OpenConnection())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, I need to make sure that `A` and `B` are called **on the same connection**. I can easily accomplish that with the [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but that also implies a transaction which I do *not* want.

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    A();

    // Now B can read the temporary table created by A.
    // However, a transaction has been started which causes problems!
    B();

    // I don't want a transaction...
    // transaction.Complete();
}
```

My question is: **How can I use this design pattern to create a "connection scope"?**

Comment: Why not use a physical table with an identifier column

Answer (score 0):

Use the same DataReader to read multiple resultsets.

```
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        A();
    }
    reader.NextResult();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        B();
    }
}
```

The same connection is used to get both resultsets.